# Any alternatives of GZIPOutputStream?

Tags: java

Sinse `GZIPOutputStream` is a subclass of `DeflaterOutputStream` which contains `protected Deflater def` which in turns overrides `finalize` method it has very large memory footprint.

```
public
class Deflater {

    //...
    protected void finalize() {
        end();
    }
}
```

Is there any alternatives? In my case I have pretty large amount of files and as a result `java.lang.ref.Finalizer` for this streams is on top of a memory dump.

Maybe there is something in 3rd party libraries?

I dumped memory from a JVM and loaded the dump into YourKit. Very large in my case means java.lang.ref.Finalizer's retained size of Deflaters is 1.6GB yet the next is int[] with just 457MB.

Comment: It's not clear what relationship you believe the finalizer has to the "very large memory footprint". What's "very large" and how have you measured that?

Comment: @JonSkeet I dumped memory from a JVM and loaded the dump into YourKit. Very large in my case means `java.lang.ref.Finalizer`'s retained size of `Deflater`s  is `1.6GB` yet the next is `int[]` with just `457MB`.

Comment: So that information should be in the question - along with sample code that reproduces the problem. Is the underlying problem *really* just that you're not allowing the objects to be garbage collected, for exmaple?

Comment: @JonSkeet In this case I noticed that about 10% of running time is spent on GC. So I supposed that it should be some memory problem...

Comment: It may well be, but that doesn't mean the problem is with `Deflater`. We can't really help without knowing more about your application.